# How do extract a substring using regular expressions in Chapel?

Tags: regex, chapel

I know that Chapel has the [Regexp Library](https://chapel-lang.org/docs/latest/modules/standard/Regexp.html) but I don't understand how to use capturing groups.  Could someone provide an example?

```
var template = "/home/user/:ID/details";
var uid = someKindaExtractyThing("/home/user/17/details");
writeln("So YOU are user ", uid, ", huh?")

> So YOU are user 17, huh?
```

This is my target.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The question already linked to the documentation so all that's really left to do is to show a code example.

```
use Regexp;

var input = "/home/user/17/details";

var capture:string;

var r = compile("""/home/user/(\w+)/details""");
var match = r.match(input, capture);

if match.matched then
  writeln(capture);
else
  writeln("not a match!");
```

The """ business will only work with master now or Chapel 1.17 or newer (otherwise you'd have to '\'-escape the '\' in a regular "string"). The [Regexp module documentation](https://chapel-lang.org/docs/latest/modules/standard/Regexp.html) has lots more details about what you can put in a regexp.

If you had multiple capture groups, you'd use more arguments to search to get them. search looks for a pattern within a string but match insists that the entire string match the pattern.

Here is an example with 2 capture groups:

```
use Regexp;

var input = "/home/user/17/details";

var part1:string;
var part2:string;

var r = compile("""/home/user/(\w+)/(\w+)""");
var match = r.match(input, part1, part2);

if match.matched then
  writeln( (part1,part2) );
else
  writeln("not a match!");
```

Comment: could you give a quick example of multiple capture groups?